# Suggested managed DNS provider?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

We own/manage a few domains (nothing too large or too trafficked). Currently our DNS servers are hosted onsite. For ease of management and lower-latency DNS requests we are interested in moving our Domains offsite, does anyone have recommendations for a good DNS provider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DynDNS.com](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/custom/)

Comment: +1 - I love DynDNS. I've used them and recommended them to Customers for years.

Comment: Also a +1 for DynDNS.

Comment: I would use DynDNS but current pricing seams prohibitive if you have ~20 domains because they will charge you 30$/year for **each** domain. Instead it looks that Zerigo is at least an order of magnitude cheaper but I never heard of them.

Answer (score 1):

[Zerigo](http://www.zerigo.com/managed-dns) offers some kickass features like a REST API, templates, and master/slave support. Relatively inexpensive, too.

Comment: 26-Nov-2017: this domain doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 1):

We've been doing some research and so far, this is the list of provider's we've got that were not mentioned already here:

- http://aws.amazon.com/route53/
- http://www.dotquad.com/
- http://dnsimple.com
- http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/dns/
- http://durabledns.com/productsandservices/dns.html

And the ones that were already mentioned:

- http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/custom/ *
- http://www.zerigo.com/managed-dns

  - it should be noted that DynDNS has two somewhat separate divisions - their consumer service and their "enterprise" platform.

Answer (score 1):

DNS made easy

http://dnsmadeeasy.com

Mahoossiive DNS providers, slightly ugly interface but its apparently getting upgraded. Should handle anything you can throw at it.

EDIT - They are pretty cheap to.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using your domain registrar to host your DNS.  It may already be provided as part of the domain registration.